# Remove hexadecimal value 0x11 from string

Tags: xml, regex, hex

I have a XML string with a 0x11 hexadecimal value hidden in it that is breaking my XmlDocument.LoadXml call.

Can someone please tell me how to find and destroy this 0x11 WITHOUT looping through all 50000 char's of the string.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've needed to do this before, and here is my code verbatim.  It reads the LineNumber and LinePosition properties to find the offending character.

It is only tested in **en-US**, but I'm not certain that this matters, as it only looks for `0x` in the exception message.

```
  internal static XmlDocument ParseWithRetry(ref string xml, string errorComment, int badCharRetryCount, Action<StringBuilder,XmlException,string> onXmlExceptionDelegate)
  {
     StringBuilder xmlBuff = null;
     if (badCharRetryCount < 0)
        badCharRetryCount = 0;
     XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
     int attemptCount = badCharRetryCount + 1;
     for (int i = 0; i < attemptCount; i++)
     {
        try
        {
           doc.LoadXml(xml);
           break;
        }
        catch (XmlException xe)
        {
           if (xe.Message.Contains("0x"))
           {
              if (xmlBuff == null)
                 xmlBuff = new StringBuilder(xml);
              // else, it's already synchronized with xml... no need to create a new buffer.

              // Write to the log... or whatever the caller wants to do.
              if (onXmlExceptionDelegate != null)
                 onXmlExceptionDelegate (xmlBuff, xe, errorComment);

              // Remove the offending character and try again.
              int badCharPosition = GetCharacterPosition (xml, xe.LineNumber, xe.LinePosition);
              if (badCharPosition >= 0)
                 xmlBuff.Remove(badCharPosition, 1);
              xml = xmlBuff.ToString();
              continue;
           }
           throw;
        }
     }

     return doc;
  }

  static readonly char[] LineBreakCharacters = { '\r', '\n' };
  internal static int GetCharacterPosition (string xml, int lineNumber, int linePosition)
  {
     // LineNumber is one-based, not zero based.
     if (lineNumber == 1)
        return linePosition - 1;

     int pos = -1;
     // Skip to the appropriate line number.
     for (int i = 1; i < lineNumber; i++)
     {
        pos = xml.IndexOfAny(LineBreakCharacters, pos + 1);
        if (pos < 0)
           return pos; // bummer.. couldn't find it.
        if (xml[pos] == '\r' && pos + 1 < xml.Length && xml[pos + 1] == '\n')
           pos++; // The CR is followed by a LF, so treat it as one line break, not two.
     }
     pos += linePosition;
     return pos;
  }
```

Comment: Great little script... You rock!!